# Can I have Excel's FIND function search only up to the column left of the current cell?

Tags: excel, function, find

I'm using the following function:

```
=FIND("x";$5:$5;7:7)*(0,25/7,5)
```

Now I would like the function to only search:

A$5:(current column -1)$5

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get the active current column - 1 you can use `=COLUMN(INDIRECT(CELL("address")))-1`, just remember to hit F9 to update that formula.

Comment: Thank you. On it's own, this works insofar that it returns the number of the column. How would I go about implementing it into my FIND function? I tried `=FIND("x";A$5:COLUMN(INDIRECT(CELL("address")))-1$5;7:7)*(0,25/7,5)`, but that returns an error. I assume because it's entering a number for the column, rather than a letter? I'm new to Excel though so I'm more than likely doing something wrong.

Comment: Since I can't edit my previous comment: Wouldn't =CELL("column")-1 return the same value?

Comment: Good shout with `=CELL("column")-1`!

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution:

```
=FIND("X";$A$5:(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(5;(CELL("column")-1))));6:6)*(0,25/7,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this function, which provide "yes" if the value "X" is founded and "no" in the opposite case.

```
IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("X",A:A,1,0)),"no","yes")
```

The second argument of the VLOOKUP function doesn't have the dollar signs so Excel will always correct the column number if you drag the cell.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't return the values in the column below 'x', like my function currently does.